# Azure Service Health | Health alerts for all types

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I am wanting to use an ARM template to deploy the following -

Service Health | Health alerts

Which will allow for these events to be covered -
Service, Planned Maintenance, Health Advisories and Security Advisory

I have been looking at this template as a base -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/resource-health-alert-arm-template-guide

But this doesn't appear to give what I am after as it appears in Monitor - Alerts

This templated seems to do some of it but I am need the other categories too but not having much luck -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/alerts-activity-log-service-notifications-arm?tabs=CLI

Wondering if anyone has come across this or is this a portal only type of setup.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly try below ARM template which includes all the events Service, Planned Maintenance, Health Advisories and Security Advisory.

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
  "actionGroups_name": {
    "defaultValue": "SubHealth",
    "type": "String"
  },
  "activityLogAlerts_name": {
    "defaultValue": "ServiceHealthActivityLogAlert",
    "type": "String"
  },
  "emailAddress":{
    "type":"string"
  }
},
"variables": {
  "alertScope":"[concat('/','subscriptions','/',subscription().subscriptionId)]"
},
"resources": [
  {
    "comments": "Action Group",
    "type": "microsoft.insights/actionGroups",
    "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
    "name": "[parameters('actionGroups_name')]",
    "location": "Global",
    "tags": {},
    "scale": null,
    "properties": {
      "groupShortName": "[parameters('actionGroups_name')]",
      "enabled": true,
      "emailReceivers": [
        {
          "name": "[parameters('actionGroups_name')]",
          "emailAddress": "[parameters('emailAddress')]"
        }
      ],
      "smsReceivers": [],
      "webhookReceivers": []
    },
    "dependsOn": []
  },
  {
    "comments": "Service Health Activity Log Alert",
    "type": "microsoft.insights/activityLogAlerts",
    "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
    "name": "[parameters('activityLogAlerts_name')]",
    "location": "Global",
    "tags": {},
    "scale": null,
    "properties": {
      "scopes": [
        "[variables('alertScope')]"
      ],
      "condition": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "category",
            "equals": "ServiceHealth"
          }
        ]
      },
      "actions": {
        "actionGroups": [
          {
            "actionGroupId": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/actionGroups', parameters('actionGroups_name'))]",
            "webhookProperties": {}
          }
        ]
      },
      "enabled": true,
      "description": ""
    },
    "dependsOn": [
      "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/actionGroups', parameters('actionGroups_name'))]"
    ]
  }
]  }
```